# Dynamic variable in JavaScript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make script with JavaScript which is dynamic, yes I know, JavaScript is always dynamic but I want to do in combination with PHP.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#glcheckmail").click(function(){
    $("#glmaildiv").load('/functions/glist-MailChecker.php');
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
echo "<div class=\"list-group-item\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"badge badge-danger\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"donothover\">Delete</a></span>
        <div style=\"white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; width:80%;\">". $row['attach_name'] ." (<i>". formatSizeUnits($row['attach_size']) ."</i>)</div></div> ";
```

As you can see I have an `"<a href="">"` with Delete in it. What I'm trying to accomplish is actually something like this (Example Not Real Code!)

```
<a href="#" id="RefToJS" onclick="<? echo $attach_id; ?>">
```

Now (hypothetically) my JavaScript should see a variable in `#RefToJS`. And I want to pass this variable on to the PHP script which loads `onclick`, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#glcheckmail").click(function(){
      $("#glmaildiv").load('/functions/glist-MailChecker.php?id='+ONCLICK_CODE);
  });
});
```

This is sort of what I want but as you can see, the code isn't a beauty and I have to little knowledge of JavaScript to make this work

Comment: The question is, why do you have to echo a value and then get that value back, wouldn't you already have that value, as you're sending it back to the same server that outputted it.

Comment: `onclick` attributes must contain valid javascript CODE. `onclick="42"` is not going to do very much for you. you'd probably want `onclick="doSomething(<?php echo $attach_id ?>)"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about it. This is how I would do it:

PHP:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='link-class' id='" . $PHP_ID . "'>Delete</a>";
```

JavaScript

```
$('.link-class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default link action
    var linkID = $(this).attr('id'); //retrieve the ID of the clicked link
    $("#glmaildiv").load('/functions/glist-MailChecker.php?id='+ linkID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first I would take an approach similar to @pmandell but I would make a few changes. First off instead of using `id` I would use a data attribute to prevent conflicts something like this:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='delete-link' data-id='{$PHP_ID}'>Delete</a>";
```

Second since you are adding these to the DOM via ajax you should use `on` to prevent issues with events not being bound to the new links you are creating. So here is what the javascript should look like:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-link',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkID = $(this).data('id');
    $("#glmaildiv").load('/functions/glist-MailChecker.php?id='+ linkID);
});
```